# AUAudioUnit & AudioUnitGetProperty, AudioUnitSetProperty

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit

With the comming of Audio Unit v3, the main class we subclass is new AUAudioUnit objective C class.

The AUAudioUnit has AUParameter implementation and is easy to work with AUParameter via AUAudioUnit.parameterTree property.

I am unable to use Audio Unit properties as AUAudioUnit do not exposes its AudioUnit property that is required as parameter

```
extern OSStatus
AudioUnitGetProperty(           AudioUnit               inUnit,
                                AudioUnitPropertyID     inID,
                                AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                AudioUnitElement        inElement,
                                void *                  outData,
                                UInt32 *                ioDataSize)
```

Currently there is no AudioUnit class property or inspection on AUAudioUnit. I am not sure how to use AudioUnit properties in AudioUnit v3 framework.

Anybody has any clue how to use AudioUnit properties in new API v3?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There's an example of how to do it in Apple's AudioUnitV3Example. Here's the code from that:

```
// Create a parameter object for the cutoff frequency.
    AUParameter *cutoffParam = [AUParameterTree createParameterWithIdentifier:@"cutoff" name:@"Cutoff"
            address:FilterParamCutoff
            min:12.0 max:20000.0 unit:kAudioUnitParameterUnit_Hertz unitName:nil
            flags: kAudioUnitParameterFlag_IsReadable |
                   kAudioUnitParameterFlag_IsWritable |
                   kAudioUnitParameterFlag_CanRamp
            valueStrings:nil dependentParameters:nil];

  // Initialize default parameter values.
    cutoffParam.value = 20000.0;
    resonanceParam.value = 0.0;
    _kernel.setParameter(FilterParamCutoff, cutoffParam.value);
    _kernel.setParameter(FilterParamResonance, resonanceParam.value);

  // Create the parameter tree.
    _parameterTree = [AUParameterTree createTreeWithChildren:@[cutoffParam, resonanceParam]];
```

(I omitted the code for resonanceParam)

There's also a great tutorial here that covers it: https://audiokitpro.com/auv3-midi-tutorial-part2/

Comment: The question asked about properties, not parameters.